# Library Mpdf (php): Set utf-8 and use WriteHTML with utf-8

Tags: php, jquery, pdf-generation, mpdf

I need help with the php Mpdf library. I am generating content for a pdf, it is in a div tag, and sent by jquery to the php server, where Mpdf is used to generate the final file.

In the generated pdf file the utf-8 characters go wrong, for example "generaciÃƒÂ³n" instead of "generación".

I detail how they are implemented:

**HTML**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

**Sending content for pdf (jquery)**

```
$('#pdf').click(function() {       
    $.post( 
            base_url,
            { 
                contenido_pdf:      $("#div").html(),
            },
            function(datos) {
            }       
    );
});
```

**Reception content (PHP)**

```
$this->pdf = new mPDF();
$this->pdf->allow_charset_conversion = true;                                
$this->pdf->charset_in = 'iso-8859-1';
$contenido_pdf  = this->input->post('contenido_pdf');

$contenido_pdf_formateado = mb_convert_encoding($contenido_pdf, 'UTF-8', 'windows-1252');
$this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($contenido_pdf_formateado);
```

**Other tested options:**

1.
$this->pdf->charset_in = 'UTF-8';

Get error:

```
Severity: Notice  --> iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string
```

2.

```
$contenido_pdf_formateado = mb_convert_encoding($contenido_pdf, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
```

or

3.

```
$contenido_pdf_formateado = utf8_encode($contenido_pdf);
```

Get incorrect characters, like the original case.

What is wrong or what is missing to see the text well? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

```
$contenido_pdf_formateado = utf8_decode($contenido_pdf);
$this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($contenido_pdf_formateado);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had used the **mode** on object creation

```
$mpdf = new Mpdf(['mode' => 'UTF-8']);
```

Use this if you are sure that your html is utf-8

Answer (score 0):

A combination of this

```
$mpdf = new Mpdf(['mode' => 'UTF-8']);
```

and the below worked for me.

```
$mpdf->autoScriptToLang = true;
$mpdf->autoLangToFont = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

the only thing you have to do to active utf-8 is to add a defult font :

i did this and  worket very well so try it and let the others knows if it's a good solotion or not.

just add a defult font and see..

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
'default_font_size' => 9,
'default_font' => 'Aegean.otf' ]);
```